"再会を果たす事なく終わっている" does this mean "ended without a reunion"?
"マリアはマルクと再会を果たす事なく終わっている。"
I'm reading this as: "Maria's reunion with Mark concludes uneventfully.", but every machine translation I use to help me analyze sentences is saying some version of: "Maria is never reunited with Mark.".
What's the correct meaning of the combination of the words "再会を果たす事なく終わっている"? And if the mtl is correct, how do those words equal ""ended without a reunion"?
I'm assuming that if every mtl comes up with generally the same thing that it must be a kind of phrase or something that I'm not aware of.
Thanks!

Yes the sentence lacks a context on what is 終わっている, and it affects the overall interpretation. MTs probably fill it with "her life".

@broccoliforest
Okay, so just making sure, my reading of the sentence is correct then?

Maybe, or maybe not. It can be correct, but whether it really is depends on the context.

@broccoliforest Okay, thank you so much!

The machine translation is correct. You seem to have missed the meaning of なく. It's the ku-form (aka adverbial form) of ない, so it roughly corresponds to English "without". It's used like so:

その本を問題なく読めた。
I could read the book without any problem.
会議はトラブルなく終了しました。
The meeting finished without trouble.

With this in mind, you can parse the original sentence like the following:

マルクと再会を果たす
to achieve a reunion with Mark
マルクと再会を果たす事
achieving a reunion with Mark
(事 is a nominalizer)
マルクと再会を果たす事なく
without achieving a reunion with Mark
マルクと再会を果たす事なく終わる
to end up without achieving a reunion with Mark
マリアはマルクと再会を果たす事なく終わっている。
Maria has ended up without achieving a reunion with Mark.
→ Maria never reunited with Mark.

